# What is the function of the phrase "with another car"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> He went off the road to avoid colliding with another car.

What is the function of the phrase "with another car"?

Comment: In English we say to collide/colliding/a collision **with** something.  "With" expresses the idea of two things coming together, in this case, it is two vehicles coming together in a collision.

Comment: If you're asking about the grammatical function of the _with_ PP, it's **complement** of the verb "colliding".

Comment: Colliding is gerund so used as a noun in this case , with pp, is adjective phrase. Right or wrong please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

> He went off the road to avoid colliding with another car.

*with another car* is a preposition phrase.  It is adjectival and modifies the gerund-participle *colliding*.

Comment: 1) Preposition phrases can be adjectival when they modify a noun or pronoun, for example "the cat *in the hat*". In this case, it is modifying the participle **colliding**, so it's an adverb preposition phrase. https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-7/prepositions/lesson-5/adverb-prepositional-phrases#:~:text=Definition%3A,)%2C%20and%20under%20what%20condition. 2) In this sentence, **colliding** is not a gerund, it's a participle. A gerund generally describes an activity "He likes swimming" whereas a participle describes an event.

Comment: It would be adjectival in "He went off the road to avoid a collision with another car." But avoid can be followed by a noun, a participle, or a noun in the objective case plus a participle.

Comment: A preposition phrase but not a modifier. Its function is that of complement of "colliding".

Comment: @JavaLatte The _with_ PP is licensed by "colliding" and thus is a complement, not a modifier.

Answer (score 0):

*Collide* comes from Latin *collidere*, which itself is constructed from (a tweaked version of) the prefix *com-*, meaning with or together. Thus *collide **with** another car* isn’t too different from *chat *with* another guest*: both colliding and chatting are activities that involve two parties.